# How to parse between two comments with Jericho?

Tags: java, jericho-html-parser

I would like to be able to parse any and all text between two comment tags using Jericho. For example,

```
<!--start-->
abc
123
<!--end-->
```

would return

```
abc
123
```

is that at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html -> Html Comments -> http://jericho.htmlparser.net/samples/console/src/FindSpecificTags.java ->

```
(...)
System.out.println("HTML Comments:");
displaySegments(source.getAllTags(StartTagType.COMMENT));
(...)
```